# Why is the C binary search implementation passing an address instead of an array?

Tags: c

I have this `C` binary search program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int element_t;

int less(a, b) {
  if (a < b)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

element_t *binary_search(element_t x, element_t *a , int n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    int mid = n / 2;
    if (less(a[mid], x))
      return binary_search(x, a+mid+1 , n-mid-1);
    if (less(x, a[mid]))
      return binary_search(x, a, mid);
    return a+mid;
    }
  return NULL;
}

int main(){

  int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  printf("%d %d", &a[2], binary_search(3, a, 5));
  return 0;
}
```

I don't get this part `a+mid+1`, it is supposed to pass an array there, but an address is instead, how is that? and array `a` `+` an integer is about address.

I read online and I can't see what is going on, because online it says `a+1` is the address of value at index 1.

Comment: I think you'll come to learn that the line between pointer and array is nearly academic at times. A pointer can be used like an array, as in `(a + n)` is `&a[n]` and `*(a + n)` is `a[n]`. A lot of the time it's just a matter of notation. In fact, in a lot of cases when you pass in what you think is an array, it "decays" to a pointer, something known as "array to pointer decay". In C arrays are really, *really* barebones. They're not proper constructs like in, say, Java or JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is that &a[2] and binary_search return a pointer so to print it out you need to use %p instead of $d:  https://onlinegdb.com/aDB1WCIjd

Comment: It might help to recall that an array is a contiguous region of memory, and a pointer can be used to address (contiguous regions of) memory.

Comment: might some some good reads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Comment: "find* some" .. geez what is wrong w me hah :(

Comment: `int less(a, b) {` You shouldn't write dinosaur C from the 1970s/1980s...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question we first need a few definitions.

### What is an array?

An array is a collection of variables of the same type which are contiguous to each other.
In C, the name of an array (in this case `a`) is a pointer to the memory position where the first element is located.

For example in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a[4]={0,1,2,3,4};
    int *ptr=&a;
    int *ptr_a=a;

    return 0;
}
```

Both pointers point to the same memory location

### What is a pointer?

A pointer is a variable which stores a memory position. Pointers have special arithmetic, when you add 1 to a pointer you are not (always) moving to the next memory position, you are adding the "weight" of the pointer type.

For example, if you have a char pointer you add by 1 byte at a time, but with int pointer you add 4 bytes(on 64-bit systems) each time you add 1.

### What happens with pointers and arrays?

Since the array name is converted to a pointer when you add a value to it, you are moving to the memory position your next element is located.
And using the `[i]` operator is equivalent to `*(array+i)`

You can(this doesn't mean you should) use arrays and pointers indistinctively.

This is called "**The Array/Pointer Duality Law**"

Comment: Wanted to make it simple, but you are right, will modify it

Comment: It is actually converted to a pointer any time it is used in an rvalue context (a context where a value is needed).

Comment: *using the `[i]` operator is equivalent to `*(array+i)`*  It's not just equivalent - [it's **defined** that way](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2)

Comment: If it is defined that way, it is equivalent, equivalent means "the same". What is the issue with that phrasing? (Not native speaker, maybe im getting something wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call a function with an array argument, such as

```
int arr[10];
...
foo( arr );
```

the compiler replaces the *expression* `arr` with something like

```
foo( &arr[0] );
```

and what the function receives is a pointer, not an array.

The `a` parameter in the `binary_search` function is a pointer, not an array, so you can do pointer arithmetic on it.

In a function parameter list any parameters declared as `T a[N]` or `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer.

There is a reason for this behavior.  The array subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given some starting address `a`, offset `i` elements and dereference the result.

However, array objects do not store an address; when you declare an array as

```
int a[10];
```

what you get in memory is

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[9]
   +---+
```

Hence the conversion rule.  Unfortunately, this means arrays lose their "array-ness" in most circumstances.